# place holder for being-downloaded photos

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

im coding an app that downloads all your fotos from fb w/o using SDK. I think it would be good if i can have a place holder for each photo(till it gets downloaded).is that possible? cud someone give some suggetions???

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to Apple's sample app called [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html).

This app displays a place holder image till the application icon is downloaded.